# is there a way to declare a variable with the value of a function which takes this declaring variable as a parameter?

Tags: function, class, kotlin

i am wondering is there some syntax in Kotlin for declaring a variable which will be equal to a function which takes several parameters 1 of which is said variable?

```
class Player(var deck: MutableList<String> = Deck().deck) {

var playerHand = Deck().deal(deck, playerHand, 6)

}

class Deck {

var deck = mutableListOf<String>()

fun deal( from: MutableList<String>, to: MutableList<String>, num: Int ){
        var temp = from.slice(0 .. num).toMutableList()
        to.addAll(temp)
        from.removeAll(temp)
    } 
}
```

So i basically want to transfer N amount of cards from a deck inside a Deck class to a variable playerHand in Player class. I know there are numerous other ways of doing it, i just wanted to know is there a way to create a var and assign a value to it using a function that takes that var as a parameter..

Comment: You can do what you're describing using a functional reference, but that's not what you're doing when you transfer items from one list to another. The properties pointing to those lists are still pointing to the same list instances after the transfer. You might have some confusion about the difference between a mutable property and a mutable collection. Combining `var` with a `MutableList` is usually a code smell, IMO. Usually if you are using a MutableList, you only want one, so you should reference it with `val`.

Comment: I have problems understanding your example. What would be the initial value of `playerHand`? You never really created a list for player hand and you would like to pass it somewhere. Maybe this is what you want: `val playerHand = mutableListOf<String>().also { Deck().deal(deck, it, 6) }`. But I think it would be better if `deal()` would just return a list of items, not write to a mutable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stared at your code for a while and finally realized what you're asking, I think: You want `playerHand` to be a MutableList whose initial values come from calling `Deck().deal()`. Like @broot says in the comment, the standard way to do this is to use `also`. I'm also assuming it's some kind of typo that you are instantiating a new Deck instance to deal from, when you already have a deck property in your class. However, that property should probably be a Deck instance directly so you still have access to the Deck functionality that goes with it.

You might consider making your Deck class implement MutableList using a delegate to simplify how it is referenced and used. Now you can directly use existing MutableList functions like `shuffle()` directly on your Deck instance. And I would use LinkedList specifically as the delegate because it is more efficient than the default returned by `mutableListOf` at removing values from the top.

I would also make the `deal` function simply a `dealTo` function because it should be assumed a Deck is only going to deal from itself.

Putting that all together:

```
class Player(var deck: Deck = Deck()) {

    val playerHand = mutableListOf<String>().also {
        deck.dealTo(it, 6)
    }

}

class Deck: MutableList<String> by LinkedList<String>() {

    fun dealTo(to: MutableList<String>, num: Int) {
        repeat(num) {
            to += removeFirst()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, .also is exactly the functionality i was looking for. Anyway i was too greedy and wanted to make 1 universal function to transfer cards from Deck to Player, from Deck to the Table from Deck to the Computer (another player), from Player to the Table and from Table to Player. I have since split it into 2 functions and overiding 1 of the for the computer behaviour.  But i now know how to instatiate lists and move N elements between them in diferrent classes using only 1 function :) thanks